# What are the supported languages with AVSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avspeechsynthesizer

AVSpeechSynthesizer seems to support english with multi delegates (britsh, us...)

Does it support other languages? french, Portuguese ... is there a list of these languages somewhere ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it does. Use `speechVoices` of [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesisVoice_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVSpeechSynthesisVoice/voiceWithLanguage:) to get a list of available voices with supported languages.

```
let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() //list of supported voices
print(voices[0].language)                          //print first voice locale
```

Currently (as of 10 September 2018, on iOS 10.3.1 and 11.4.1) you'll find these:

- ar-SA
- cs-CZ
- da-DK
- de-DE
- el-GR
- en-AU
- en-GB
- en-IE
- en-US
- en-ZA
- es-ES
- es-MX
- fi-FI
- fr-CA
- fr-FR
- he-IL
- hi-IN
- hu-HU
- id-ID
- it-IT
- ja-JP
- ko-KR
- nl-BE
- nl-NL
- no-NO
- pl-PL
- pt-BR
- pt-PT
- ro-RO
- ru-RU
- sk-SK
- sv-SE
- th-TH
- tr-TR
- zh-CN
- zh-HK
- zh-TW

Answer (score 0):

these two little functions will help:

```swift
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

func getSpeechSupportedRegionalLanguages() -> [String] {
    let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
    var languages: Set<String> = []
    let english = Locale(identifier: "en")
    voices.forEach{languages.insert(english.localizedString(forIdentifier: $0.language)!)}
    return Array(languages).sorted()
}

func getSpeechSupportedLanguages() -> [String] {
    let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
    var languages: Set<String> = []
    let english = Locale(identifier: "en")
    voices.forEach{languages.insert(english.localizedString(forLanguageCode: $0.language)!)}
    return Array(languages).sorted()
}
```

## 2024.02.17 result

### without regional variants (33 total):

1. Arabic
2. Bulgarian
3. Catalan
4. Chinese
5. Croatian
6. Czech
7. Danish
8. Dutch
9. English
10. Finnish
11. French
12. German
13. Greek
14. Hebrew
15. Hindi
16. Hungarian
17. Indonesian
18. Italian
19. Japanese
20. Korean
21. Malay
22. Norwegian Bokmål
23. Polish
24. Portuguese
25. Romanian
26. Russian
27. Slovak
28. Spanish
29. Swedish
30. Thai
31. Turkish
32. Ukrainian
33. Vietnamese

### with regional variants (44 total):

1. Arabic (world)
2. Bulgarian (Bulgaria)
3. Catalan (Spain)
4. Chinese (China mainland)
5. Chinese (Hong Kong)
6. Chinese (Taiwan)
7. Croatian (Croatia)
8. Czech (Czechia)
9. Danish (Denmark)
10. Dutch (Belgium)
11. Dutch (Netherlands)
12. English (Australia)
13. English (India)
14. English (Ireland)
15. English (South Africa)
16. English (United Kingdom)
17. English (United States)
18. Finnish (Finland)
19. French (Canada)
20. French (France)
21. German (Germany)
22. Greek (Greece)
23. Hebrew (Israel)
24. Hindi (India)
25. Hungarian (Hungary)
26. Indonesian (Indonesia)
27. Italian (Italy)
28. Japanese (Japan)
29. Korean (South Korea)
30. Malay (Malaysia)
31. Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)
32. Polish (Poland)
33. Portuguese (Brazil)
34. Portuguese (Portugal)
35. Romanian (Romania)
36. Russian (Russia)
37. Slovak (Slovakia)
38. Spanish (Mexico)
39. Spanish (Spain)
40. Swedish (Sweden)
41. Thai (Thailand)
42. Turkish (Türkiye)
43. Ukrainian (Ukraine)
44. Vietnamese (Vietnam)

Comment: Instead of stating the date, specify which version of iOS it's for.